# How to pass variables from a PowerShell task to job and stages

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm trying to understand how to pass environment variables between Azure Pipeline tasks, jobs, and stages.  I created a PowerShell task to define variable, according to the docs, but I can't seem to see them after my task completes.  Here is a snippet that shows the stage that I create, with jobs and tasks.  I'm trying to set the FOO variable in the 'PassVariable' task and then access it from the 'PowerShell' task.

Unfortunately, FOO is never passed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Test
  jobs:
  - job: SetSemVer
    displayName: 'Test Var Passing'
    steps:
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Pass Variable'
      name: PassVariable
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FOO;isOutput=true]Hello World)"

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
      name: PowerShellTask
      env:
        myVar: $FOO
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "Foo: $FOO"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the name in the power shell task, we need to print the variable via `$($env:PASSVARIABLE_FOO)` or `$(PassVariable.FOO)` instead of `$FOO`. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable)

[image]

In addition, we can print the variables via bash cmd printenv and check the variables defined in the script

YAML sample

```
trigger: none
stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Test
  jobs:
  - job: SetSemVer
    displayName: 'Test Var Passing'
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Pass Variable'
      name: PassVariable
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FOO;isOutput=true]Hello World"
    
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'printenv'
        
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
      name: PowerShellTask
      env:
        myVar: $FOO
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "Foo: $($env:PASSVARIABLE_FOO)"
```

Result:

[image]